# Adding an UIImageView to a UITableViewCell programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` that shows videos with their thumbnail images. I'm adding the thumbnail `UIImageView` programmatically. However, when I have more than 1 row in my `UITableView`, the cells' `UIImageView` shows in every other cell. For example, if I have 2 cells, the `UIImageView` appears fine in cell 1, but the cell 2 `UIImageView` shows in cell 3. Sorry if that is confusing. Let me know if there's more information needed.

Here is the code I use in `cellForIndexPath`:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("videoCell")! as! VideoCell
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None // get rid of highlight when tapping a cell

    if videoCollections.count > 0 {
        let singleVideoCollection = videoCollections[indexPath.row]
        // get video clips from PFRelation
        let clips = singleVideoCollection.relationForKey("clips")
        let query = clips.query()

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (clipObjects, error) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                for (index, clip) in (clipObjects?.enumerate())! {
                    if index == 0 { // first clip

                        let firstThumbnailImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 54, height: 54))
                        firstThumbnailImageView.center = cell.center
                        firstThumbnailImageView.layer.cornerRadius = firstThumbnailImageView.frame.height / 2
                        firstThumbnailImageView.clipsToBounds = true
                        let thumbnail = clip.objectForKey("thumbnail")
                        thumbnail!.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                            if (error == nil) {
                                firstThumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(data:imageData!)
                                cell.contentView.addSubview(firstThumbnailImageView)
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return cell

    }
}
```

This is the outcome when I have 2 cells. Notice how the second `UIImageView` is in a third cell:
[image]

Comment: ok I added my full cellForRow method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` finishes downloading the `imageData`, cell object might already have been reused for a different indexPath.
And as you are use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` and `cell.contentView.addSubview()`,you will add too much subviews.
So you can try the follow code.

```
class VideoCell: UITableViewCell {
//......
let firstThumbnailImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 54, height: 54))

override func prepareForReuse() {
  super.prepareForReuse()
  firstThumbnailImageView.image=nil;
}
//......
}


func tableView(tableView : UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath : NSIndexPath)->UITableViewCell {
//......
// let firstThumbnailImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 54, height: 54))

cell.firstThumbnailImageView.center = cell.center
cell.firstThumbnailImageView.layer.cornerRadius = firstThumbnailImageView.frame.height / 2
cell.firstThumbnailImageView.clipsToBounds = true
let thumbnail = clip.objectForKey("thumbnail")

//......

//cell.contentView.addSubview(firstThumbnailImageView)

//......
}
```

Comment: I tried your answer but the image is now not showing at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not understand the reusing of the tableview cell well, it is recommended that you set the hidden property of the UI elements binding with the indexPath in the delegate method.

add code like this

```
if (clipObjects![indexPath.row].objectForKey("thumbnail")) {
    thumbnail.hidden = false
} else {
    thumbnail.hidden = true
}
```